# R-style axes with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using ggplot, is it possible to get "R-style" x/y axes that don't meet at the origin and that instead consist of two disconnected ranges, as in the following example?

[image]

The reason here is mainly to get ggplot plots to look consistent next to pure-R ones.

Comment: this begs the question, why not make base plots [look like ggplot2?](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips:graphics-misc:ggplot2theme_inbase) ;)

Comment: Because I can neither update nor redo the base plots.  I've actually considered editing the SVG of the ggplot-generated ones, but that's such a hack.

Comment: If you want to digitize the base plots, you could try the package `digitize`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this,

```
library(ggplot2)

d <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=rnorm(10))

base_breaks_x <- function(x){
  b <- pretty(x)
  d <- data.frame(y=-Inf, yend=-Inf, x=min(b), xend=max(b))
  list(geom_segment(data=d, aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend), inherit.aes=FALSE),
       scale_x_continuous(breaks=b))
}
base_breaks_y <- function(x){
  b <- pretty(x)
  d <- data.frame(x=-Inf, xend=-Inf, y=min(b), yend=max(b))
  list(geom_segment(data=d, aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend), inherit.aes=FALSE),
       scale_y_continuous(breaks=b))
}

ggplot(d, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
       panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
       panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  base_breaks_x(d$x) +
  base_breaks_y(d$y)
```

[image: screenshot]

Edit: a [related issue has since been discussed](https://github.com/jrnold/ggthemes/pull/18) in the ggtheme package, and potentially provides a cleaner solution (no need to provide the data explicitly to the breaks function).

Comment: Very nice! I thought of using opts(axis.line = theme_line()), but I get very strange errors there...