# Using opts to change axis.line in ggplot2 doesn't function. How to do this?

Tags: r, ggplot2

While trying to get the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808761/r-style-axes-with-ggplot) the obvious way, I ran into a rather unexpected error. I tried to set the option `axis.line` in the theme using the function `opts()`, tried to update it using `theme_update()`, but all to no avail. Each time when I tried it, I got the same error :

> ```
> Error in validDetails.polyline(x) : 
>   It is invalid to specify both 'id' and 'id.lengths'
> ```

Some example code giving this error:

```
require(ggplot2)

Data <- data.frame(autos=c(
  sample(1:4,8,TRUE),
  sample(6:9,4,TRUE),
  11,18
  ))

ggplot(Data,aes(autos)) + 
  geom_histogram(fill='lightblue',colour="black",binwidth=5) +
  opts(axis.line=theme_line(), panel.border=theme_blank())
```

Any idea what I am overlooking?

Comment: try `theme_segment()` instead

Comment: [the reason being](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/guides-axis.r#L56) that `axis.line` is fed four arguments with the intent that they be used by `segmentGrob`, not `polylineGrob` (hence the cryptic error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ggplot2 wiki at https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/-opts()-List contains helpful information.

Each option is described, together with the type of theme it needs.  From this page:

```
...
axis.title.y (text)
axis.line (segment)
...
```

So, use `theme_segment` in your opts:

```
ggplot(Data,aes(autos)) + 
  geom_histogram(fill='lightblue',colour="black",binwidth=5) +
  opts(axis.line=theme_segment(), panel.border=theme_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, both for the solution and the link.