# R-style axes with ggplot - again

Tags: r, ggplot2, axes

I have the same question that was posted here earlier:
[R-style axes with ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808761/r-style-axes-with-ggplot)
I have tried the solution which was suggested by baptiste:

```
library(ggplot2)

d <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=rnorm(10))

base_breaks_x <- function(x){
  b <- pretty(x)
  d <- data.frame(y=-Inf, yend=-Inf, x=min(b), xend=max(b))
  list(geom_segment(data=d, aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend)),
       scale_x_continuous(breaks=b))
}
base_breaks_y <- function(x){
  b <- pretty(x)
  d <- data.frame(x=-Inf, xend=-Inf, y=min(b), yend=max(b))
  list(geom_segment(data=d, aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend)),
       scale_y_continuous(breaks=b))
}

ggplot(d, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  opts(panel.border = theme_blank(),
       panel.grid.major = theme_blank(),
       panel.grid.minor = theme_blank()) +
  base_breaks_x(d$x) +
  base_breaks_y(d$y)
```

and found that this is only working when the plot aesthetics
just consists of aes(x,y). Drawing data from a frame where
one column contains a factor by which the colour is changed, e.g.

```
d <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=rnorm(10),name=rep(c("blue","red"),5))
ggplot(d, aes(x,y,colour=name))+ ...
```

gives the error message

```
"Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'name' not found"
```

How can this problem be solved?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: there's a cleaner solution IMO as an open feature request for the ggtheme package: see the [discussion here](https://github.com/jrnold/ggthemes/pull/18)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got this error because you set `colour=name` inside the `ggplot()` call and `base_breaks_x()` and `base_breaks_y()` contains `geom_segment()` calls that also tries to find variable `name` inside the dataframes of those functions. There are two ways to solve the problem.

First, move `colour=name` from `ggplot()` to `aes()` of `geom_point()`.

```
ggplot(d, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour=name))
```

Second, modify functions `base_breaks_x()` and `base_breaks_y()` by adding `inherit.aes=FALSE` inside the `geom_segment()` calls.

```
geom_segment(data=d, aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend),inherit.aes=FALSE)
```

Comment: yes!! and now I understand the inner workings of ggplot even better! thanks!